Ошибка aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL content
В общем, пишу бота, который отправляет пользователю audio файла по ссылке, т.е ты даешь боту ссылку на видео, а он тебе отправляет аудио файл. Чтобы это реализовать, решил использовать библиотеку pytube.
async def callback_command(callback: CallbackQuery):
link = callback.data
yt = YouTube(link)

stream = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).last().url
await bot.send_audio(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, audio=stream)

Тут в итоге в stream сохраняется ссылка на файл, и если тыкнуть на него, то он тебя перекидывает на браузер с этим аудио.

Думал все ок, но в итоге получаю ошибку
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL content
Подскажите, как это можно исправить?

Никто не обещал, что ютубовская ссылка будет рабочей для посторонних — она может быть привязана к вашему IP-адресу, например

ну видимо так. Поэтому и не получается аиограму отправить мне этот аудио. Тогда как это можно исправить?
